# Textualizer effect html not working

Tags: html

Can't get this textualiser effect to work - getting a blank screen. I have copied it from this site: http://vimeo.com/39150670. And have tried inserting into visual studio and notepad but still no luck!

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kiro.me/textualizer/javascript/textualizer.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#txtlzr { font-size: 150px; width: 960px; height:250px; }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="txtlzr"> </div> </body>
<script>
    $(function() { 
        var list = [ 'Text 1','Hello World','Screencasts'];
        var options = {
        duration: 1000,          // Time (ms) each blurb will remain on screen
        rearrangeDuration: 1000, // Time (ms) a character takes to reach its position
        effect: 'random',        // Animation effect the characters use to appear
        //centered: true           // Centers the text relative to its container
    }
       var txt = $('#txtlzr');
       txt.textualizer(list, options); // textualize it!
        txt.textualizer('start'); // start
       });

</script>






</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to load the plugin is not working, so use an updated one, for that replace your following line:

```
<script src="http://kiro.me/textualizer/javascript/textualizer.min.js"></script>
```

for this one:

```
<script src="http://raw.github.com/krisk/textualizer/master/textualizer.min.js"></script>
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kkFnf/)